# Specker order-an associated defnition

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I was looking for the definition of **Specker order** and I've found one [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82575804.pdf) on page $13.$ However I do not know what is $I^2$ in *Notation* under item $(3)$ intended to mean. This is not needed for Specker order itself but for ${}^*[I]$ only. Also $I^1$ would be of interest to me.

[image]

Comment: Is $I^n$ not defined in *Notation*, on page 1?

Comment: Good. I've skipped onto the middle and overlooked it. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the notation $I^n$ is used differently in the passage quoted in the question than in the definition on page 1.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's an important observation. So, what does my $I^2$ mean in the passage quoted ? And also $I^1$ ? This can be done only by Saharon :-)

Comment: @AndreasBlass But on the last line in the snippet he uses $I^n$ in the sense of page 1, doesn't he ?

Comment: The notation $I^n$ is used in its page 1 meaning in (5) and also in the first line of the "Notation" under (3) in the snippet. But on the last two lines of that "Notation" under (3), $I^1$ and $I^2$ are just bound variables for two linear orders, and Saharon is defining what it means for them to be near. (And $I_1$ and $I_2$ are also bound variables.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass In fact, it was really weird for me that what you call "bound variables" were intended in the sense of page $1$. It's clear now, though.